# How to get the count of occurrences in one table and update another table to that value?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to write an SQL statement that will:

- Count the number of rows in the table `booking` that are *open* and where the `booking.postcode` is "MK"
- Take a note of the plot (in `booking.plot_id`), and then update the table `plot.jobs` with the value count

For example running the SQL query when `booking` table has the following rows:

[image]

Would see the following highlighted values in `plot.jobs` being updated to 1:

[image]

This my code so far (note I am using [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html)):

```
public int CountBooking()
{
    string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM booking WHERE postcode=MK AND status=open";
    int count = -1;
    // ExecuteScalar will return one value
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
    count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");
    // Close
    CloseConnection();
    return count;
}
```

If there were 3 rows with a plot_id of 4, and 6 rows with a plot_id of 6, then the highlighted values will be updated to 3 and 6 respectively.

How would I go about achieving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close on the first part. If you want the number of openings for each plot_id, you'll need to use that in your GROUP BY statement like this:

```
SELECT plot_id, COUNT(*) AS numOpenings
FROM bookings
WHERE postcode = 'MK' AND status = 'open'
GROUP BY plot_id;
```

You can use that as a subquery in your UPDATE statement by joining it to the plot table and updating the matching rows, like this:

```
UPDATE plot p
JOIN(
  SELECT plot_id, COUNT(*) AS numOpenings
  FROM bookings
  WHERE postcode = 'MK' AND status = 'open'
  GROUP BY plot_id) temp ON temp.plot_id = p.plot_id
SET p.jobs = temp.numOpenings;
```

This worked out in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d6ed/1). Let me know if you have more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Never used Connector/Net but I would do something like this:

Run this query to retrieve the plot_id and JobCount:

select plot_id, count(*) JobCount from booking where postcode = 'mk' and status = 'open' group by plot_id;

Then scroll through this result set and issue update commands like this:

Update Jobs set jobs = [JobCount] where plot_ID = [plot_id]

Note the values of [JobCount] and [plot_id] will come from your first query.